# assignment overriden to keep changing original instance variable in Python class

Tags: python

Basically, this is what the problem is. I have a class with an optional parameter: lst. lst is a nested list. Below is a method that returns another instance of the class that it is inside.

```
self.lst = [[[1, 2]]] # this is defined in the constructor
s = self.lst
for a in s:
    for b in a:
        if b[0] != item:
             b[0] = 5
return ChangeNumb(lst=s)
```

What happens after this is VERY weird. Returning ChangeNumb.lst is now [[[5, 2]]], but the class that the method is run in ALSO ChangeNumb.lst == [[[5, 2]]].

So that instead of just returning a new instance of a class with a different parameter, this method changes the self.lst of the class it is inside as well.

I need to make it so that self.lst does not change, while returning a new instance.

PLEASE HELP

EDIT: Although I've encountered a similar problem when writing the class constructor, I was able to resolve it as -> self.lst = lst.copy(); however, s = self.lst.copy() does not work!

Comment: `list.copy` isn't a method that exists.  To copy a list, you can just slice it:  `lst[:]`.

Comment: list.copy() runs because it's a method of a list object; I've just tried lst[:] but it's the same result.

Comment: @mgilson: It was introduced in 3.3.

Comment: The slice copy will not work in this case, it just copies the reference, use `copy.deepcopy()`

Comment: @user2357112 -- Thanks.  I knew it was proposed, (and I think it's a good decision to add it).  I'm glad you mentioned it to document for others who come across this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a copy in order not to modify self.lst.
For simple lists just `list()` is enough, but as you have nested lists you should use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

So you could change your declaration with something like :

```
s = copy.deepcopy(self.lst)
```

Comment: I think you need to copy the list before it is mutated in the loop. Try `s = copy.deepcopy(self.lst)`, then keep the return as it was.

Comment: Can you explain to me how I can use deepcopy? Cause I've tried a = [[1]] b = a.deepcopy() but it just returns AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'

Comment: @Charlie: `import copy` then `b = copy.deepcopy(a)`